# Run Function on Variable Change

Tags: javascript, variables, rxjs

Let's assume I have a variable:

```
var x = 0;
```

Each time this variable gets modified I want to run a function:

```
function(){
    console.log('x has been changed');
}
```

Would RxJs be appropiate for this task? If not, what other approach would work better?

Comment: Make a function to vary that variable, instead of the other way around. `function setX(newX) { window.x= newX}` or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set value to property of an object, use `set`, `get`.

```js
const x = {};

let value = 0;

function fn(oldValue, newValue) {
  console.log(`${oldValue} has been changed to ${newValue}`);
}

Object.defineProperty(x, "prop", {
  get() {
    return value
  },
  set(val) {
    fn(value, val);
    value = val;
  }
});

x.prop = 1;

x.prop = 10;
```

Comment: @AndreiRosu Note, the order of function call and assignment within `set` should probably be `value = val; fn(value, val)` to reflect actual change in value of `value`, rather than assignment occurring at next line.

Comment: sidenote, if you use `Object.defineProperty(window, "prop", {` its actully answers the OP's question, i.e `prop = 1`

Answer (score 2):

Douglas Tyler finished his answer before I had the chance to but yes, proxy is definitely something that you might use and here's an example :

```
const obj = {
    _id: null,
    set id(str) {
        console.log('setting the value !');
        this._id = str;
    },
    get id() {
        return this._id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a good bet would be to use [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), although this only works for objects, arrays and functions. Another option would be checking the value of on an interval and comparing it to the old value of x which you've stored in another variable, though this may not work for your purposes. I think your best option would be to always set x with a function that does whatever other functionality you want it to.

Answer (score -2):

You can use interval. Although I use Angular to $watch, you can see its implementation. There is also object.watch functionality but last i checked was not working in other browsers. So below is code using intervals (not a fun of intervals though)

```
var x=0, xWatcher = 0;
setInterval(function() {
   if ( x !== xWatcher ) {
      xWatcher = x;
      //Your code here
      xChanged()
   }
}, 50); // any delay you want 

function xChanged(){
   console.log('x has been changed');
}
```